# execution order - new object's function undefined

Tags: javascript

I've created an app object which contains an empty modules object within it defined in the constructor.

```
var App = function() {
    this.modules = {};
};
```

The modules object contains references to other objects (modules) that make up the app and contain their logic.

I instantiate the app like this

```
window.app = new App();
app.createModules();
```

createModules() fills the modules object with the modules of the app. Then when it is done, it runs initModules() that calls each modules init() function. In this way I hope to be able to control the execution order so that objects dependent on other objects will load correctly. The code for this is as follows:

```
App.prototype.createModules = function() {
    console.log("Creating Modules");
    this.modules = {
        radio: new Radio(),
        visualiser: new Visualiser()
    };
    this.initModules(this.modules);
}
App.prototype.initModules = function() {
    console.log("Initialising modules");
    for (var key in this.modules) {
        if (this.modules.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var obj = this.modules[key];
            console.log(obj);
            console.log(obj.init); //logs 'undefined'
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the console log on obj.init is returning undefined, meaning that I can't run the init code for that object. But when the page is finished loading if I call

```
app.modules.radio.init
```

It returns the function. I can't seem to figure out why is this happening.

Cheers!

**EDIT**
Here is the structure of app:

```
var app = function() {
   ...
}

window.app = new App();
app.createModules();

function Radio() {
    ...
}
Radio.prototype.init = function() {
    ...
}

function Visualiser() {
    ...
}
Visualiser.prototype.init = function() {
    ...
}

//Event code
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvggLZ?editors=0011

Comment: I cannot see where you define `obj.init`.

Comment: obj.init is just a reference to the module while looping inside the initModules function. 
var obj = this.modules[key];
so console.log(obj) returns: 
'Radio {settings: Object}'. Every module is defined as an object with prototype methods and every module has an init() protype function

Comment: Where are Radio.prototype.init and Visualizer.prototype.init defined?

Comment: Well, the correctness of your example may depend on how (and when) is obj.init defined, so I think it is important to add that information.

Comment: Can you post the constructor and init method of Radio?

Comment: I've edited the post so you can clearly see the structure of the app and where the objects live :)!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm. I apologise if this question isn't quite clear enough. I'll make a codepen and get back to you!

Comment: [Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/r6f43wgr/)  I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: Hi, I've created a codepen which reproduces the error:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvggLZ?editors=0011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is the structure of app

Yes, that calls the methods before they are created on the prototypes. Move the

```
window.app = new App();
app.createModules();
```

to the bottom of the script and it will work.

Comment: Thankyou! I needed to move the initialise code above to the bottom and between my events code.